# Is it wise to sell company stock to pay down a mortgage?

Tags: investing, mortgage

Is it wise to sell company stock to pay down a mortgage? Say, you have $25,000 and a $100,000 mortgage. Is it better to continue to assume the risk over the long haul or cash in at a reasonable amount. I could doubled the value of my initial investment at the time of this writing.

Comment: What rate of return are you getting (and do you reasonably expect to be getting) on the stock? What rate of interest are you paying on the mortgage? Over what time period? You need to run the numbers, take risk into account and then make a decision; there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: I assume you mean "I *have* doubled the value of my initial investment" - why do you think that's relevant to your decision?  [Mr. Market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Market) is offering you $25,000 today for something he could easily offer you pennies for tomorrow, regardless of how much the offered price has risen in the past.  If you're happy with his offer today, you're doing yourself a disservice by blindly hoping the price will continue to rise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by "Company Stock" you mean "stock in the company I work for" then absolutely sell your stock.  It is too big a risk to have your investments tied into the same company that is also providing your salary.

If you mean stock as in general investments, I like to look at it this way.   If you have $25,000 stock and a $100,000 mortgage you ask this question:

**If I had a $75,000 mortgage would I borrow an additional $25,000 against my house to invest in the stock market?**

If the answer is yes, then you are taking a risk consistent with your tolerance for risk.   If you answer no, then your tolerance for risk says you'd be happier paying down your mortgage.

Comment: Interesting approach to developing a feel for the risk involved.

Comment: Not just interesting, this is the critical question to ask whenever weighing investment decisions - failing to consider the inverse question (would I willingly go deeper into debt to make this investment in the first place, etc.) is probably the single biggest mistake individual investors make.

Comment: The price was up this morning and I sold it off. I plan to pay down the mortgage once the funds become available. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If I owned stocks in the company I worked for and those stocks were rising strongly due to the company producing consistently good results with increasing revenues, increasing profits and increasing dividends, then there would be no way I would sell those stock at the moment. If on the other hand they were a terrible company with a falling share price, I would sell them straight away - whether I worked for the company or not. This is terrible advice to give someone without knowing anything about them or the stock they own. If you were a Financial Planner you could get sued for this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if your stock is still rising in price keep it. If it is falling in price sell it and pay off your mortgage.

To know when to do this is very easy. If it is currently rising you can put a trailing stop loss on it and sell it when it drops and hits your stop loss.

A second easy method is to draw an uptrend line under the increasing price and then sell when the price drops down below the uptrend line, as per the chart below.

[image: Uptrend Broken]

This will enable you to capture the bulk of the price movement upward and sell before the price drops too far down. You can then use the profits (after tax) to pay down your mortgage.

Of course if the price is currently in a downtrend sell it ASAP.

Comment: Don't for get to take advantage of any CGT allowance and taper relief as selling stock immediately might trigger a bigger tax bill.

Comment: @Pepone - firstly there is no mention the OP is in a country with discounted long term capital gains. But secondly and more importantly, what is the use of holding onto an asset just to pay less capital gains if that asset is dropping in price. I would rather make $10k in capital gains and pay half in tax than make zero in gains and pay no tax.